# Show certain user's blog posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, blogs

Well, started to learn rails and of course started by writing a service with personal blogs (something like livejournal). I have posts scaffold and user model (thanks to Devise). Now I'm trying to show all posts by certain user with something like /username/posts in url but really can't understand how to make this rails-way.
Already made nested resources in routes

```
resources :users do 
  resources :posts 
end
```

and connected user and post models with

```
has_many :posts
```

and

```
belongs_to :user
```

Should I create controller for user or not? Is there any proper way for this?

P.S. Thanks for the answer. Trying to study rails but almost every tutorial I found ends with scaffolding and that's not very helpful.

Edit 1: Thanks to the "match" idea I solved half of the problem. The other (unsolved) half is selecting posts written by certain user

Edit 2: Added

```
@user = User.where(:username => params[:username])
@posts = @user.posts
```

To controller, but I have "undefined method `posts'" error in posts controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `where` you get an array of objects from the query, not a single object.
And because of this you don't have the `posts` method on your `@user` variable.
Maybe you should change to something like this, to retrieve only one `user`:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

This way you have only one `user` queried and you can use the `.posts` relashionship without errors.

Comment: Wow, thanks! You really saved me from another day of useless searching!

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
resources :users do
   resources :posts 
end
```

you will end up having urls like '/users/1/posts'

First to have username in case of id you need to write

```
def to_param
  self.username 
end
```

in your user model.

Or if you don't want your url to be /users/:id/posts you can create a route url using match

```
match ':username/posts' ,'posts#show'
```

which will take you to the posts controller and show action.

Comment: also about the controller you should do a before_filter in the PostsController to get the user from username so it will be accessible in every action so it's Dryer then doing that in every action

Comment: Thanks for you answer! "match" idea really helped me, but I really can't understand how to select posts only from certain user