# Rails Multiple-User Blog Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I need a little bit of help on RESTful routing. Basically, im trying to recreate http://medium.com to help improve my skills in rails.

I have the registration done via Devise.

Im stuck at the actual blog routing. I want the routes to be something like this: `domain.com/username/post-title`. Im not sure if it is possible to make this kind of app follow the restful pattern.

How would I do it?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
scope module: :username do
  resources :posts
end
```

but when I rake routes, I just get something weird:

```
 posts GET    /posts(.:format)                  username/posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                  username/posts#create
  new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)              username/posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)         username/posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)              username/posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)              username/posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)              username/posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)              username/posts#destroy
                root GET    /                                 home#index
```

The url for these routes still stay `/posts` and for some reason arent `:username/posts`.

I really dont know how to apprach this.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You should read more on routing here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Also you must have the relationship defined in your models

Comment: Read more on it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888587/show-certain-users-blog-posts-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using 'scope'. Try using 'namespace' instead if you want the module name in your url

```
namespace :username do
  resources :posts
end
```